# how to load with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I try to give data with param using Route
and using param, get data from server and print it.
but useEffect doesn't work

```
export default function Board({ match }) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
    });
    console.log(content);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>hi</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/board/:number"
            authenticated={this.state.authenticated}
            component={Board}
          />
```

[image]

Comment: The `useEffect` callback code is 100% synchronous, so it won't, and can't, wait for the Promise chain to resolve and enqueue the state update. Also, even if you moved the console log ***into*** the Promise chain, because React state updates are asynchronously processed you'll still only log the state from the current render cycle, not what it will be on a later render cycle after it's processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to receive the url parameters from the `useParams` hook.

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Board() {
  ...

  const { number } = useParams(); // get url parameters 

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
    });
    console.log(content);
  }, []);

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getonepost function is not defined as a async function. Please use this code.

```
useEffect(() => {
getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
  setContent(response);
  console.log(content);
});
```

}, []);
or you can try this either.

```
const [ update, setUpdate]=useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
          console.log(content);
        });
        
      }, [update]);

    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
          setContent(response);
          setUpdate(!update);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `match.params.number` to useEffect as second argument.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
    });
    console.log(content);
  }, [match.params.number]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getOnePost` is an asynchronous promise. So attempting to `console.log(content)` on the next line will not wait for the promise to resolve, and will log the initial value of `[]`.

This is expected behaviour.

If you really want to log the value of `content` when it changes, add another `useEffect` with a dependency on `content` and put the `console.log` there.

```
export default function Board({ match }) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(content);
  }, [content])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>hi</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see, you are using `console.log` outside the `.then` statement, as you are writing asynchronous code it will `console.log` the `content` first then make a request to the server. if you want to see `response`, `console.log` it inside the then statement like this:-

```
  const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
      console.log(response);
    });
    
  }, []);
```

and if you want to check weather it is stored in state or not you can do this:-

```
const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOnePost(match.params.number).then((response) => {
      setContent(response);
    });
    
  }, []);
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(content)
}, [content])
```

the first `useEffect` run to get data from `api` and second run when `content` state changes.